# jquery datatable add row undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In attempting to add a row to the jquery DataTable I am do the following:

```
//add new status row to the DataTable
$('#errorTable').dataTable().fnAddData( [
     id,
     msg,
     tm
]);
```

I used to use the code below `table.row.add([...])` to add a row - and it did work for awhile however all of the sudden it is giving me the following error:

> Unhandled exception at line 102, column 17 in
>   http://127.0.0.1:45319/js/errors.js?v=3
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'add' of
>   undefined or null reference

```
var table = $('#errorTable').dataTable();
table.row.add([
    id,
    msg,
    tm
]).draw();
```

In fact doesn't the jQuery documentation use the table.row.add code in it's own example. My question is why doesn't it work and why does the fnAddData work? What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `DataTable()` to get access to newer API methods introduced in version 1.10+. For example:

```
var table = $('#errorTable').DataTable();
table.row.add([id, msg, tm]).draw();
```

You can continue using old API with `dataTable()`, for example:

```
$('#errorTable').dataTable().fnAddData([id,msg,tm]);
```

Comment: Thank you Gyrocode - I didn't realize the difference between DataTable() and dataTable().